# Are there any CSS properties that can not be inlined?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I say inline, I mean placing CSS properties within the style attribute.

Is there a way to determine with Javascript if a particular property can not be inlined or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Css properties can all be used,

but you cannot use [pseudoclasses and pseudoelements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) like `:hover`, `:after` `:nth-child()` etc.

Comment: You can't use any selectors at all, can you?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Thank you for your second answer today - really helping me out here! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can inline every style you can define in a *normal* STYLE element or in an external style sheet (see section 14.2.2 of [HTML specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html)).

You can't use, as pointed by Gaby, any selector. They say:

> For example, for [[CSS2]] inline style, use the declaration block syntax described in section 4.1.8 (without curly brace delimiters).

The [section 4.1.8](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-CSS2-19980512/syndata.html#declaration) describes *declarations and properties*, not rules and selectors so the content of the STYLE attribute is limmited to properties only.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any (standard) CSS that can't be written inline, but you couldn't declare a class or pseudoclass inline for instance.

Inline is a valid place to define CSS, so any CSS will work there else the precedence of CSS (C=*cascading*) would be broken.